# Why doesn't sys.settrace fire when there's no main function?

Tags: python

```
import sys

def printer(frame, event, arg):
    print(frame, event, arg)
    return printer

sys.settrace(printer)
x = 1
sys.settrace(None)
```

The above code won't print anything. https://repl.it/@laike9m/settrace

If I create a main function and put `x = 1` into it, things work as expected

```
import sys

def printer(frame, event, arg):
    print(frame, event, arg)
    return printer

sys.settrace(printer)

def main():
    x = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.settrace(None)
    # outputs
    # <frame object at 0x7f16e5264d88> call None
    # <frame object at 0x7f16e5264d88> line None
    # <frame object at 0x7f16e5264d88> return None
```

https://repl.it/@laike9m/settracehasmain

I'm using Python 3.6+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs time!

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys.settrace)

settrace(...)
    settrace(function)

    Set the global debug tracing function.  It will be called on each
    function call.  See the debugger chapter in the library manual.
```

The key-phrase here is "*function call*". `main()` is a function call. `x = 1` isn't. Simply put, `sys.settrace` *does* fire, but the tracing function isn't called when there is no function call.

---

Interestingly, the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) word it differently:

> **The trace function is invoked** (with *event* set to `'call'`) **whenever a new local scope is entered**; it should return a reference to a local trace function to be used that scope, or `None` if the scope shouldn’t be traced.

<sup>*(Emphasis added.)*</sup>

Since calling a function enters a local scope, the trace function will be invoked. But in addition to calling functions, the docs state that other forms of local scope also work:

```
import sys

def printer(frame, event, arg):
    print(frame, event, arg)
    return printer

sys.settrace(printer)

class A:
    print(1)

sys.settrace(None)
```

Output (some paths replaced by `...` by hand):

```
<frame at 0x7fa1a4d184b0, file '/.../example.py', line 9, code A> call None
<frame at 0x7fa1a4d184b0, file '/.../example.py', line 9, code A> line None
<frame at 0x7fa1a4d184b0, file '/.../example.py', line 10, code A> line None
1
<frame at 0x7fa1a4d184b0, file '/.../example.py', line 10, code A> return None
```