# How to trace code run in global scope using sys.settrace?

Tags: python

Say I have a piece of code like this:

```
import sys

def printer(frame, event, arg):
    print(frame, event, arg)
    return printer

sys.settrace(printer)
x = 1
sys.settrace(None)
```

Since

> The trace function is invoked (with event set to 'call') whenever a new local scope is entered

The above code outputs nothing. See my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55998475/2142577).

So is there a way to trace lines in global scope, like `x = 1`?

Comment: See the accepted anwswer @MagnusLindOxlund

Comment: Great, so I assume it worked for you to use both `sys.settrace(printer)` and `sys._getframe().f_trace = printer`. That didn't work for my scenario, so I was wondering if the answer suggested diving deeper than the example provided.

Comment: There's also `watchpoints.watch`, e.g., `watchpoints.watch(x)`, which will automatically output to stderr when the variable is accessed, but the current release apparently has some trouble with globals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys.settrace` sets the *global* trace function. This trace function is the one invoked whenever a new Python stack frame is entered (`'call'` events), and its return value is the new scope's *local* trace function. The *local* trace function of the active stack frame is the one used for all other event types.

You need to set the local trace function of an existing stack frame, but setting the global trace function doesn't help you do that. To set an existing frame's local trace function, you can *manually assign* the `f_trace` attribute of the frame object to the function you want. For example, to set the current frame's local trace function:

```
import sys
sys._getframe().f_trace = whateverfunc
```

Note that local trace functions will not be invoked if there is no global trace function, so you need to set the global trace function too. (This doesn't seem to be documented.)

You can combine `sys.settrace` and manual `f_trace` assignment to trace both new and existing stack frames; for example, on a `'return'` event, you can check the local trace function of the frame you're about to return to and set that trace function to whatever you want. The [`bdb` debugger framework source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/bdb.py) is a good example of how to work with trace functions.

Comment: Thanks. I use `sys._getframe().f_trace = printer` to replace `sys.settrace(printer)`, still got no output. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @laike9m: You have to also set the global trace function. Local trace functions aren't called if there's no global trace function. This is one of the weird, undocumented details of Python debugging support.

Comment: wow, that's crazy, thanks so much... Is 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/29500737d45cbca9604d9ce845fb2acc3f531401/Python/ceval.c#L4526:
where this behavior happens?

Comment: @laike9m: That's an important part of it. The [`sys.settrace` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/sysmodule.c#L556) is also important, particularly `trace_trampoline`, a C-level trace function distinct from the Python-level function passed to `settrace`, and used for both local and global trace function calls. Ctrl-F-ing for `call_trace` in `ceval.c` also turns up a bunch of relevant code.