# How to the get previous of last line number of the previous frame in python

Tags: python

I am calling a function `log()` of another module, and I need to get the line number of the last statement was before calling this `log()` function, like how we get the line number where an exception occurred.

Using this `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno` gives me the last line number of the previous frame.
But I want to get its previous line number.
Example:

```
Line 1: if True:
Line 2:     print("Expecting the line no = 2")
Line 3: else:
Line 4:     pass
Line 5: log() -> it gives me line 5 but I need line 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) with a trace function that keeps track of each line number being executed and store it in a queue of size 2 so that the line prior to a call to the `log` function will be available at the start of the queue. Stop tracking line numbers when inside the log function to avoid the log function itself tainting the queue:

```
import sys
from collections import deque

class Tracer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.linenos = deque(maxlen=2)

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'line' and frame.f_code is not self.log.__code__:
            self.linenos.append(frame.f_lineno)
        return self.trace

    def log(self):
        print(self.linenos[0])

tracer = Tracer()
sys._getframe().f_trace = tracer.trace
sys.settrace(tracer.trace)

if True:
    assert True
else:
    pass
tracer.log()
```

This outputs: `21` (the line number of the `assert` statement)

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/MatureIntentionalTrapezoids

Comment: Python is truly amazing. Is "this is not possible" ever an answer?

Comment: Can you explain the line `sys._getframe().f_trace = tracer.trace`?

Comment: It's rare indeed to find anything that Python can't do. The fact that everything is an object in Python makes Python so powerful and flexible. It should be noted that `sys._getframe().f_trace = tracer.trace` is needed to enable tracing at the module level. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998616/how-to-trace-code-run-in-global-scope-using-sys-settrace